# Same-origin policy and mark.js

Tags: javascript, php, html, iframe, same-origin-policy

I'm currently working on a search engine for work. While debugging my code, I just found out about the concept of Same-origin policy.

I'm having troubles understanding all the implications of this policy, but maybe you can help me out :

Basically, I want to highlight words in the HTML pages i'm displaying in iframes, using a variable containing the whole HTML code of the pages.

My mark.js is not highlighting anything inside the iframes (while the option iframes:true is set) and I was wondering if this was in any way related to this Same-origin policy ?

I don't know if i'm being clear i'm sorry, my English is a little bit rusty. Don't hesitate to ask for more precisions.

Have a nice day !

Comment: Why do you think it's about same origin policy?
Is you iframe from a different domain?

Comment: I think they can be. I'm displaying old newsletters from various websites, directly by implementing their HTML code into the iframes